# Contour area does not show all the relevant areas

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

I am trying to identify all circles in an image. After enhancing contrast, use threshold, use canny edges I find all contours and loop through them, which ever has area>0 I present on the result image. The results are not good. Please assist...

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
void changeGain(cv::Mat&,double,int);


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

// Load the original image and make a duplication
cv::Mat rawImage = cv::imread("..\\3.png");
cv::Mat duplicateImage= rawImage.clone();

// Add contrast
changeGain(duplicateImage,1.9 ,-240);


// Apply thershold
cv::threshold( duplicateImage, duplicateImage, 150, 200, cv::THRESH_BINARY );


// Use canny edges
cv::Mat img_canny;
cv::Canny(duplicateImage,img_canny,150,200);

// Find all the contours from the canny image
vector<vector<cv::Point>> contours;
findContours(img_canny, contours, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

// Approximate contours to polygons + get circles
vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly;

for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
{
    double area = contourArea(contours[i],true);
    if (area > 0 )
        contours_poly.push_back(contours[i]);
}

// Draw the circles on the image
drawContours(rawImage, contours_poly, -1, Scalar(rand() & 255, rand() & 255, rand() & 255));

// Show result
cv::imshow("Final Result", rawImage);
cv::waitKey(0);
imwrite("..\\contour_result.jpg",rawImage);

}

void changeGain(cv::Mat& image,double alpha, int beta)
{
//cv::Mat new_image = cv::Mat::zeros( image.size(), image.type() );

 /// Do the operation new_image(i,j) = alpha*image(i,j) + beta
 for( int y = 0; y < image.rows; y++ )
 {
     for( int x = 0; x < image.cols; x++ )
     {
         for( int c = 0; c < 3; c++ )
             image.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x)[c] =
                     cv::saturate_cast<uchar>( alpha*( image.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x)[c] ) + beta );

    }
 }

 return;
```

}

This is the original image

[image: This is the original image]

This is the result when showing all contours

[image: This is the result when showing all contours]

This is the result when showing only contours with area >0

[image: This is the result when showing only contours with area >0]

An image after thershold

[image: An image after thershold]

[Image after canny](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEcM4.jpg)

Comment: Any chance you could save a reference to the thresholded image? That would be most helpful for debugging

Comment: Added the image after thershold to the original post. @PatrickRoberts

Comment: Looking at the threshold, it appears that blobs with edges that jut out are causing your contours to not fully close the loop. Do you see that?

Comment: To combat this, consider adding [erosion and dilation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html) before doing your threshold, and see if that removes the jagged edges around the circles that are causing open contours. It should fix the problem, but your contours may be less precise around the edges of the circles.

Comment: why do you want contours with positive *oriented* area ? can't you just filter out not sufficiently 'circular' contours (according to some proper statistics)?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, I see what you mean. However I am using the canny image (just posted that as well) for the contour, so I don't think the jagged edges are the case. Having said that, I am willing to try out just about anything:)

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes, thanks for replying. I'm afraid I did not understand. Besides area, how can I filter out not sufficient 'circulars' contours?

Answer (score 0):

First, consider using morphology (https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html) in order to clean up then thresholded image. Using something like opening and then closing will remove noise and fill gaps in the thresholded image.

Second, you don't need to detect Canny edges. You can extract the contours from the thresholded just fine, it's what I'm doing for my current project.

Third, I assume you are looking for circles, in which case you can use `minEnclosingCircle` (https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga8ce13c24081bbc7151e9326f412190f1). Since the shape is a circle it should enclose just the circle, something you could determine by comparing the `contourArea` of a contour and the area of a circle with the radius returned by `minEnclosingCircle`. If your contour is indeed a circle this ratio should be close to 1. (This is also a technique I'm currently using).

Comment: Thanks, Oscar. I will try and see how it goes